# Strange issue adding fragments dynamically android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a strange issue when I add a new fragment dynamically.

The problem is that I can add only one fragment or an array with all the fragments that I want to add.

This is my code:

```
    ArrayList<Uri> uriArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    uriArrayList.add(Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/1"));
    uriArrayList.add(Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/2"));
    uriArrayList.add(Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/3"));
    uriArrayList.add(Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/4"));
    uriArrayList.add(Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/5"));

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, numeroDeVistas, this, this, imagenUri, uriArrayList);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And then in the adapter instantiate the fragment in the next way:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
   return Imagen.newInstance("Array", uriArrayList.get(position));
}
```

The problem is that when I start the apllication the images are shown like this:

media/2 - media/2 - media/3 - media/4 - media/5

If I swipe to the last position and back the images are show correctly:

media/1 - media/2 - media/3 - media/4 - media/5

The same if I am in the media/3 and turn the mobile the image are show like this:

media/4 - media/4 - media/5

I don´t know why the current fragment showing at the beginning are changes for the next fragment.

Any help are welcome.

Thanks!!!

Comment: looks like something is counting from 1, something else is counting from 0... Hard to tell

Comment: try using this function with the adapter setOffscreenPageLimit(5)

Comment: pager.setOffscreenPageLimit() method doesn't work.

Comment: For some reason that I don't undestand we can't call the fragments in this way to fill the Imageviews. If you use the example in the link below the imageViews are filled correctly. http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery-swipe-gallery/